# Alter View in Sybase ASE Database

Tags: sql, database, sap-ase

im using Sybase ASE database and i used the sql below to create a view in database:

```
create view dbo.vb_user_list (db_name, user_email, user_sex) as
select  'db01' ,
        email,
        sex
from    db01.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1

union

select  'db02'  ,
        email,
        sex
from    db02.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1
```

this view show all user from db01 and db02, and it works.

but when i want to alter this view to show user from db03 also, i make a sql like below:

```
alter view dbo.vb_user_list (db_name, user_email, user_sex) as
select  'db01' ,
        email,
        sex
from    db01.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1

union

select  'db02'  ,
        email,
        sex
from    db02.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1

union

select  'db03'  ,
        email,
        sex
from    db03.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1
```

but its with below error message:

```
 [ALTER - 0 rows, 0.002 secs]  [Code: 102, SQL State: 37000]  Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

i don't understand why, can anybody help?

Comment: What happens if you just query select  'db03'  ,
        email,
        sex
from    db03.dbo.emp_hdr
where   enable = 1

Comment: @MrSlim just tried it, no problem, it works.

Comment: Delete the view and create a new one?

Comment: @sibert ya, it will works, just wonder why can't use alter view syntax. I'm still very grateful to you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't stated your ASE version so there are a couple answers:

- for ASE versions up to 15.7, you need to drop and then (re)create the proc; you'll need to make sure you grab a copy of your permissions and any auditing settings before you drop the view as these settings will also need to be recreated once the view has been recreated
- for ASE 16.x, you can use the `create or replace view` command; while this is basically the same as `drop view` + `create view`, the one benefit is that any settings (eg, permissions, auditing settings) will remain in place

Answer (score 1):

You have to drop and then (re)create your view. `Alter View` not supported by Adaptive Server Enterprise.

Refer [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3421724) for more info.